# How can I recognize "PNG (Portable Network Graphics)" files in numpy.ndarray?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I need to find `png` files in `numpy.ndarray`. It is even possible?

`list_of_files` contains files with the extension `['jpg', 'jpeg', 'bmp', 'tif', 'tiff', 'png']`.

```py
for f in list_of_files:
    stream = open(f, 'rb')
    bytes = bytearray(stream.read())
    numpy_array = numpy.asarray(bytes, dtype=numpy.uint8)
image = cv2.imdecode(numpy_array, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
```

Comment: You should imdecode the string itself, not the numpy array. What do you mean "png files IN the array" ?

Comment: Is there a reason you just not open the files with png extension? Are you also trying to find the png files that has no extension or false extension?

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to process just the `png` files, how about loading just those? You can use the `glob` library for this:

```
import glob

my_path = "<path_to_folder>"
for f in glob.glob(my_path + "/*.png"):
    #Do whatever here
```

Essentially, `glob.glob(my_path + "/*.png")` gives you a list of the files in your path who have the desired extension.

Answer (score 0):

You could identify the `.png` file before reading the image:

```
images={'png':[],'others':[]}
for f in list_of_files:
    if f.split('.')[1:] == 'png':
        with open(f, 'rb') as stream:
            bytes = bytearray(stream.read())
        img_array = numpy.asarray(bytes, dtype=numpy.uint8)
        images['png'].append(cv2.imdecode(img_array, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED))
    else:
        # w/e you want to do with the other images
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `imghdr.what`.

```
import imghdr

for f in list_of_files: 
     if (imghdr.what(f) == "png"): 
          print(f + " is a PNG file")
```